# Azure Function does not always fetch document with input DocumentDB binding on subsequent requests

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-functions

My scenario: with a message coming from an Azure Storage Queue I want to either create or update a document in DocumentDB

- I set the DocumentDB consistency to **Strong**, so that it is
  guaranteed that the document is updated
- I use a Singleton/Listener,
  so that only one Queue entry is processed at a time

Here is my code:

**function.json**

```
{
  "disabled": false,
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "updateEntry",
      "type": "queueTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "queueName": "update-log",
      "connection": "AzureWebJobsStorage"
    },
    {
      "type": "documentDB",
      "name": "inputDocument",
      "databaseName": "logging",
      "collectionName": "messages",
      "id": "{id}",
      "connection": "documentDB",
      "direction": "in"
    },
    {
      "type": "documentDB",
      "name": "outputDocument",
      "databaseName": "logging",
      "collectionName": "messages",
      "createIfNotExists": true,
      "connection": "documentDB",
      "direction": "out"
    }
  ]
}
```

**run.csx**

```
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

[Singleton(Mode = SingletonMode.Listener)]
public static void Run(UpdateEntryType updateEntry, TraceWriter log, DocumentType inputDocument, out DocumentType outputDocument)
{
    log.Info($"update entry:{updateEntry.id} {updateEntry.created} {updateEntry.Event.ToString()}");

    outputDocument = new DocumentType();
    outputDocument.Events = new List<JObject>();

    if (inputDocument == null)
    {
        outputDocument.id = updateEntry.id;
        outputDocument.created = updateEntry.created;
    }
    else
    {
        log.Info($"input document:{inputDocument.id} {inputDocument.created} {inputDocument.Events.Count}");
        outputDocument.id = inputDocument.id;
        outputDocument.created = updateEntry.created.CompareTo(inputDocument.created) < 0 ? updateEntry.created : inputDocument.created;
        outputDocument.Events.AddRange(inputDocument.Events);
    }

    outputDocument.Events.Add(updateEntry.Event);

    log.Info($"output document:{outputDocument.id} {outputDocument.created} {outputDocument.Events.Count}");
}

public class UpdateEntryType
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string created { get; set; }
    public JObject Event { get; set; }
}

public class DocumentType
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string created { get; set; }
    public List<JObject> Events { get; set; }
}
```

My problem: most of the times an actual existing document is found with **id** and hence updated - but not for at least 5% of the time

My questions (before I open a case @MSFT support):
What am I missing? Is this the right approach or is it destined to fail anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Queue batchSize 1 instead of SingletonMode.Listener made the problem disappear.

**hosts.json**

```
{
  "queues": {
    "batchSize": 1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> not for at least 5% of the time

From my experience, If it is a **dedicated**  plan, we need to turn on **Always On** setting for our Function App.

> The Function runtime will go idle after a few minutes of inactivity, so only HTTP triggers will actually "wake up" your functions. This is similar to how WebJobs must have Always On enabled.

More detail info about **Consumption Plan** &  **Dedicated App Service Plan** and how to set appsetting, please refer to [Enable Always On when running on dedicated App Service Plan](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/wiki/Enable-Always-On-when-running-on-dedicated-App-Service-Plan).

[image]

Comment: As I have this Function App on a Consumption pricing tier you would suggest to re-create it with a Dedicated App Service Plan?

Comment: Thanks @Tom Sun - I did some thorough testing: application re-activation / startup was not the issue.I solved the Problem with batchSize 1 on my queue listener.

Comment: Congratulates. Please help to mark  your answer that will help more communities that have the same issue.